# When should I use subprocess.Popen instead of os.popen?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Seems both executes a subprocess and create a pipe to do in/out, just that the `subprocess` is newer.

My question is, is there any function that `subprocess.Popen` can do while `os.popen` cannot, so that we need the new module `subprocess`?

Why Python language didn't choose to enhance `os.popen` but created a new module?

Comment: See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/ Motivation & Rationale sections: protect against some security risks, сross-process exceptions, better operations with file descriptor, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: Never use `os.popen`, always use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)!

As you can see from the Python 2.7 [`os.popen` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen):

> Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is obsolete. Use the
>   `subprocess` module. Check especially the [Replacing Older Functions
>   with the subprocess
>   Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) section.

There were various limitations and problems with the old `os.popen` family of functions. And as the docs mention, the pre 2.6 versions weren't even reliable on Windows.

The motivation behind `subprocess` is explained in [PEP 324 -- subprocess - New process module](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324):

> **Motivation**
>
> Starting new processes is a common task in any programming language,
>   and very common in a high-level language like Python. Good support for
>   this task is needed, because:
>
> - Inappropriate functions for starting processes could mean a
>     security risk: If the program is started through the shell, and
>     the arguments contain shell meta characters, the result can be
>     disastrous. [1]
> - It makes Python an even better replacement language for
>     over-complicated shell scripts.
>
> Currently, Python has a large number of different functions for
>   process creation.  This makes it hard for developers to choose.
>
> The subprocess module provides the following enhancements over
>   previous functions:
>
> - One "unified" module provides all functionality from previous
>     functions.
> - Cross-process exceptions: Exceptions happening in the child
>     before the new process has started to execute are re-raised in
>     the parent.  This means that it's easy to handle exec()
>     failures, for example.  With popen2, for example, it's
>     impossible to detect if the execution failed.
> - A hook for executing custom code between fork and exec.  This
>     can be used for, for example, changing uid.
> - No implicit call of /bin/sh.  This means that there is no need
>     for escaping dangerous shell meta characters.
> - All combinations of file descriptor redirection is possible.
>     For example, the "python-dialog" [2] needs to spawn a process
>     and redirect stderr, but not stdout.  This is not possible with
>     current functions, without using temporary files.
> - With the subprocess module, it's possible to control if all open
>     file descriptors should be closed before the new program is
>     executed.
> - Support for connecting several subprocesses (shell "pipe").
> - Universal newline support.
> - A communicate() method, which makes it easy to send stdin data
>     and read stdout and stderr data, without risking deadlocks.
>     Most people are aware of the flow control issues involved with
>     child process communication, but not all have the patience or
>     skills to write a fully correct and deadlock-free select loop.
>     This means that many Python applications contain race
>     conditions.  A communicate() method in the standard library
>     solves this problem.

Please see the PEP link for the Rationale, and further details.

Aside from the safety & reliability issues, IMHO, the old `os.popen` family was cumbersome and confusing. It was almost impossible to use correctly without closely referring to the docs while you were coding. In comparison, `subprocess` is a godsend, although it's still wise to refer to the docs while using it. ;)

Occasionally, one sees people recommending the use of `os.popen` rather than `subprocess.Popen` in Python 2.7, eg [Python subprocess vs os.popen overhead](http://essays.ajs.com/2011/02/python-subprocess-vs-ospopen-overhead.html) because it's faster. Sure, it's faster, but that's because it doesn't do various things that are vital to guarantee that it's working safely!

---

FWIW, [`os.popen` itself still exists in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen), however it's safely implemented via `subprocess.Popen`, so you might as well just use `subprocess.Popen` directly yourself. The other members of the `os.popen` family no longer exist in Python 3. The `os.spawn` family of functions still exist in Python 3, but the docs recommend that the more powerful facilities provided by the `subprocess` module be used instead.