# Achieving shell-like pipeline performance in Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, pipe

[Edit: Read accepted answer first. The long investigation below stems from a subtle blunder in the timing measurement.]

I often need to process extremely large (100GB+) text/CSV-like files containing highly redundant data that cannot practically be stored on disk uncompressed. I rely heavily on external compressors like lz4 and zstd, which produce stdout streams approaching 1GB/s.

As such, I care a lot about the performance of Unix shell pipelines. But large shell scripts are difficult to maintain, so I tend to construct pipelines in Python, stitching commands together with careful use of `shlex.quote()`.

This process is tedious and error-prone, so I'd like a "Pythonic" way to achieve the same end, managing the stdin/stdout file descriptors in Python without offloading to `/bin/sh`. However, I've never found a method of doing this without greatly sacrificing performance.

Python 3's documentation recommends [replacing shell pipelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) with the `communicate()` method on `subprocess.Popen`. I've adapted this example to create the following test script, which pipes 3GB of `/dev/zero` into a useless `grep`, which outputs nothing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from shlex import quote
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from time import perf_counter

BYTE_COUNT = 3_000_000_000
UNQUOTED_HEAD_CMD = ["head", "-c", str(BYTE_COUNT), "/dev/zero"]
UNQUOTED_GREP_CMD = ["grep", "Arbitrary string which will not be found."]

QUOTED_SHELL_PIPELINE = " | ".join(
    " ".join(quote(s) for s in cmd)
    for cmd in [UNQUOTED_HEAD_CMD, UNQUOTED_GREP_CMD]
)

perf_counter()
proc = Popen(QUOTED_SHELL_PIPELINE, shell=True)
proc.wait()
print(f"Time to run using shell pipeline: {perf_counter()} seconds")

perf_counter()
p1 = Popen(UNQUOTED_HEAD_CMD, stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(UNQUOTED_GREP_CMD, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
p2.communicate()
print(f"Time to run using subprocess.PIPE: {perf_counter()} seconds")
```

Output:

```
Time to run using shell pipeline: 2.412427189 seconds
Time to run using subprocess.PIPE: 4.862174164 seconds
```

The `subprocess.PIPE` approach is more than twice as slow as `/bin/sh`. If we raise the input size to 90GB (`BYTE_COUNT = 90_000_000_000`), we confirm this is not a constant-time overhead:

```
Time to run using shell pipeline: 88.796322932 seconds
Time to run using subprocess.PIPE: 183.734968687 seconds
```

My assumption up to now was that `subprocess.PIPE` is simply a high-level abstraction for connecting file descriptors, and that data is never copied into the Python process itself. As expected, when running the above test `head` uses 100% CPU but `subproc_test.py` uses near-zero CPU and RAM.

Given that, why is my pipeline so slow? Is this an intrinsic limitation of Python's `subprocess`? If so, what does `/bin/sh` do differently under the hood that makes it twice as fast?

More generally, are there better methods for building large, high-performance subprocess pipelines in Python?

Comment: Is this really the kind of data that should be processed locally? It sounds like it needs some kind of cluster technology

Comment: In most cases, the time to upload the data to another server is immensely greater than the runtime of the shell scripts I'm replacing. Any DBMS/Hadoop-like/"big data" tool I know of would take much longer still to ingest/ETL the data, let alone do the processing of my scripts. The tasks I'm considering are all perfectly viable on a single laptop today, and could be written in Bash. I just prefer Python control flow and would like to avoid shelling out if possible.

Comment: That's fair enough, I was curious whether the whole project should be hoisted into the cloud so the infrastructure already exists :)

Comment: BTW, the use of `shell=True` here is... unfortunate. If your `substring_which_will_never_be_found` contained `$(rm -rf ~)` in it, or -- worse -- `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'`, you'd have a **very** bad day. (Relying on `shlex.split()` isn't good form either -- if you have a name with a space, you want to keep it as *one name*; populate an array or tuple by hand, and you don't need to worry about your content being munged).

Comment: ...moving towards the topic -- **yes**, `subprocess.PIPE` **is** a high-level abstraction for connecting file descriptors; **no**, the data isn't copied into the Python process's namespace. Why you're seeing a difference here is a good question -- I'd need to dig in; wouldn't be surprised if it were related to buffering settings on the file descriptors.

Comment: Charles: Using `shell=True` seemed appropriate given the point was to demonstrate how Python performs when invoking `/bin/sh`, and the arguments are not even variables. If I had called `/bin/sh` explicitly the same quoting issues would exist in the arguments. I am aware shell quoting is error-prone, which is why I'm asking the question in the first place.

Comment: The entirely-aside-the-question point I was trying to make is that code that showcases `shell=True` without steps to do it safely -- say, `subprocess.Popen(['head -c "$1" /dev/zero | grep "$2"', '_', str(byte_count), 'substring_that_will_never_be_found'], shell=True)` as an example as such a safe usage -- is increasing the number of bad-practice examples on the Internet. Yes, it's safe in the example at hand because your strings are all fixed, but if it's not obvious to a reader that it's safe *only* in that circumstance, someone can take away the wrong lesson.

Comment: ...see https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/0960ba9a2758961b464b3467c3312e47 as a concrete proposal.

Comment: Ironically, the "safer" version of the code fails to run because `BYTE_COUNT` isn't cast to `str`. It's also far less clear in this form what `PIPE_CMD` actually looks like after it's assigned when you have to nest list comprehensions to create it. I do agree with you that your style is better for real code, but for an illustrative example I like it as is. If you start questioning every fixed string, you can't write anything. What if `grep` or `head` are programs that might have spaces in the path? How easy is it to read the code once you address that possibility?

Comment: It's cast in the `quote(str(s))` path; admittedly, that's the only portion I actually tested. `f"${SOURCE_CMD} | ${GREP_CMD}"` is the line in the original that it hurts me to look at, and which inspired the proposal: On its own, it's combining content from variables to generate a string parsed to a shell, which is in general a practice it's best to discourage. Yes, if someone looks at how the variables are generated it's safe, but we're a teaching resource here -- we should be setting a good example wherever possible, and that means not depending on analysis or context for safety.

Comment: (In the bash community, one of the things that's a constant source of problems is TLDP's "ABS" documentation, which pays very little care to modeling good practices in code incidental to the purpose of an example. Unfortunately, people don't only learn whatever the example is intended to illustrate -- they also pick up practices from context, and in freenode's #bash channel, one of our huge ongoing challenges is helping people unlearn bad habits they picked up from the ABS... which is how this is something I came to be sensitive about).

Comment: I've modified the example to incorporate your suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're timing it wrong. Your `perf_counter()` calls don't start and stop a timer; they just return a number of seconds since some arbitrary starting point. That starting point probably happens to be the first `perf_counter()` call here, but it could be any point, even one in the future.

The actual time taken by the `subprocess.PIPE` method is 4.862174164 - 2.412427189 = 2.449746975 seconds, not 4.862174164 seconds. This timing does not show a measurable performance penalty from `subprocess.PIPE`.

Comment: Wow, I am dumb. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Also, take this into account, for `Popen`:

> Changed in version 3.3.1: bufsize now defaults to -1 to enable
>   buffering by default to match the behavior that most code expects. In
>   versions prior to Python 3.2.4 and 3.3.1 it incorrectly defaulted to 0
>   which was unbuffered and allowed short reads. This was unintentional
>   and did not match the behavior of Python 2 as most code expected.

Answer (score -1):

In python3 there is "the python way" and "the one we don't mention". (Though it pains me to abuse RAM, there does seem to be rather a lot of it available these days.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# how you are "meant" to do it
import subprocess
ps = subprocess.Popen(('ip', 'a'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pt = subprocess.Popen(('grep', '192'), stdin=ps.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pu = subprocess.Popen(('awk', '{print $2}'), stdin=pt.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pv = subprocess.Popen(('sed', 's;/.*;;'), stdin=pu.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#ps.wait()
#ps.stdout.close()
output = pv.communicate()[0]
print(output.decode('utf-8').rstrip())

# OR (the 1 we don't mention)
import os
print(os.popen('ip a|grep 192|awk \'{print $2}\'|sed \'s;/.*;;\'').read().rstrip())

# or (the 1 we don't mention, pretending to be PEM compliant)
cmd="ip a|grep 192|awk '{print $2}'|sed 's;/.*;;'"
print(os.popen(cmd).read().rstrip())
```

Comment: Seems some pythonistas like to bite at information that might be helpful without explaining their objection.

Comment: I think the downvote (not by me) is likely due to your answer being bad in multiple ways. First, you do not answer the question of the OP; second, you do not explain what you are doing; third you are using a deprecated function (`os.popen`) which, in Python 3, is implemented using `subprocess.Popen` anyway, as can be seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678241/7738328; and fourth, comes with not explained assertion that it somehow absues RAM.